# How to join results of different with clause

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have the following data structure:

```
table user
user_id | year_month | fruit  
------------------------------
1       | 2021-01    | orange
1       | 2021-01    | apple
1       | 2021-01    | melon
1       | 2021-01    | orange
1       | 2021-02    | kiwi
1       | 2021-02    | orange
1       | 2021-02    | banana
1       | 2021-02    | melon
1       | 2021-02    | orange
1       | 2021-03    | melon
1       | 2021-03    | orange
1       | 2021-03    | melon
1       | 2021-03    | banana
1       | 2021-03    | apple
```

I want to generate this output

```
 user_id | year_month |            fruits            |  most_frequent
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 2021-01    | orange, apple, melon         | orange
1        | 2021-02    | kiwi, orange, banana, melon  | orange
1        | 2021-03    | melon, orange, banana, apple | orange
```

It is basically a grouping of the fruits consumed by `year_month`. Notice that the last column it is the most consumed fruit of **all the time** and not only the month.

This is my code so far:

```
WITH user AS (

 -- logic to retrieve the results from 2 other tables and aggregate into 1 temporary table
 -- contains a function inside

), ranking AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        fruit,
        COUNT(*) AS most_frequent, 
        FROM
            user
        GROUP BY 
            1, 2
        ORDER BY 
             3 desc
        -- LIMIT 1
)

SELECT
  user.user_id,
  user.year_month,
  STRING_AGG(distinct user.fruit, ', ') as fruits,
FROM user
LEFT JOIN ranking 
ON user.user_id = ranking.user_id
WHERE user.user_id = 1
GROUP BY  1
        , 2
ORDER BY 2
```

and this is my output:

```
 user_id | year_month |            fruits            
-----------------------------------------------------
1        | 2021-01    | orange, apple, melon         
1        | 2021-02    | kiwi, orange, banana, melon  
1        | 2021-03    | melon, orange, banana, apple
```

I'm having problems with the most frequent column. My initial solution was to uncomment that `limit 1` line in the `WITH ranking AS` and include `ranking.fruit` into the main select, but this way I got no data returned.

To be more confusing for me, if I run this `ranking` code outside the `with` clause - including with the `limit` line, I got the desired grouping I mentioned in the 'initial solution'. So the problem seems to be related to some join question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select user_id, year_month, 
    string_agg(distinct fruit) as fruits
  from user
  group by  user_id, year_month
) join (
  select user_id, fruit
  from user
  group by user_id, fruit
  qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by user_id order by count(*) desc)
)
using (user_id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Can you explain the `qualify` line, please?

Comment: using `qualify` you can filter in only most frequent (`count(*) desc`) fruit per user